# Force and Kinetic Energy on a Speed Bump

Tags: energy

I have done a basic calculation of the force at an angle on the speed bump when the car makes a contact on it (please check the attached image), now I wanted to calculate the kinetic energy that I can get from this considering the vehicle is 1850 kg and travelling at 15 mph from this force. I have also calculated the potential energy that I can get from the car just using gravity and the mass. Once I obtain that how do I add both the energies? Can I just add them or is there an equation for it?

The main aim here is to calculate the energy that I can get when a car at 15 mph hits a speed bump.

[image]

Comment: You may find this helpful : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/24759/10902

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy in this case is horizontal and it doesn't have any interaction with the potential. The potential isn't really much to consider since a speed bump is so near to ground level and to harness that energy, the bump has to sink to ground level as each wheel pairs stands on it. The amount of energy absorbed by the bump equal to the difference between the kinetic energy for the initial velocity just before the car hits the bump and final velocity just after leaving it. I'm not sure what you intend to use the energy for, but it doesn't work like you're approaching it. Your attached math is right by the way.

Comment: Thanks @TechDroid, I am trying to study some of the prior attempts where people tried to collect energy by making the speed bump collapse to the ground and coupling that with the generator, Just trying to learn how much energy those devices can harness with these kinetic energy from the vehicle. Also, thanks for validating my math.

Comment: The bump will become less useful as a speed suppressor if you want to harness all the energy, both pot. & kin. involved. The best approach I can think of right now is to make the bump into segmented long plates across the road with set of rods/pistons pointing towards the common center of the arc. Then there will exist a mechanism below the pavement independently converting the gradual linear depression of each plate into rotation as the vehicle crosses, this way you optimize harnessing both the potential and kinetic energy and still have the bump work as a bump. Note: GRADUAL DEPRESSION.

Comment: that is a great input, I will surely look into it! Thank you